# How much would Blender benefit from multiple core / threads?

Tags: rendering, shaders, performance

I'm currently building a PC for game development (and regular gaming of course :P) and I have all of my parts chosen (Radeon RX 580, 16gb Corsair vengeance, 256gb m.2, 1 TB HDD, MSI B450 Gaming Plus) and I was wondering whether to get the Ryzen 5 2600 or shell out an extra hundred for the Ryzen 7 2700, since as far as I can tell the only major benefit the 2700 has is its 8 core / 16 threads VS the 2600's 6 core / 12 threads. Will the thread/core difference impact rendering/shading in any meaningful way?

Comment: Hello :). Check https://opendata.blender.org/. When comparing results for [2600 and 2700](https://opendata.blender.org/benchmarks/query/) you can see cca 10% improvement in render times.